# Is it possible to vsync a single buffered context?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am writing time critical code for a scientific application that uses OpenGL to perform rendering. The device I'm controlling appears like a computer monitor. the dream is refresh the device at exactly 60 hz.

I tried to use a single buffer raster mode, but I am having trouble getting the vsync to work. In double buffered mode it works.

Can you vsync a single buffered context?

Works

```
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 24;
pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
```

Doesn't work

```
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 24;
pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
```

*edit*

At the end of my render loop

```
glFlush();
glFinish();
swapBuffers();//GDI?
```

Comment: In double buffering, it is the `wglSwapBuffers` call that waits until the next vsync.  With single buffering, you render directly to the stream in one continuous sequence of commands.  Which function call do you think should wait until the next vsync?

Comment: In Direct3D, you can call [`IDirect3DDevice9Ex::WaitForVBlank `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174349.aspx).  I'm pretty sure that OpenGL does not have a standard function to block the calling thread until the VSYNC interrupt occurs, but there are some vendor-specific extensions.

Comment: In single-buffering mode, there is `glFlush()` which is basically the equivalent of `glSwapBuffers()`.

Comment: @YohanDanvin: `glSwapBuffers` implies `glFlush`/`glFinish`, but the reverse is not true.  You can easily have multiple flush fences per frame (and you will if you're rendering to an aux buffer and then using that as a source texture)

Comment: I know. My comment was more aimed at @Mikhail *hint hint*: you should provide more info regarding what you're doing and what you mean by 'Doesn't work'.

Comment: @BenVoigt I made the change.

Answer (score 2):

In order to synchronize buffer swap with the screen refresh (what vsync does), you are going to need to actually have multiple buffers to swap. Thus, double buffering is going to be necessary.

The way to enable vsync once you have double buffering is platform dependent, though as a.lasram indicated, WGL_EXT_swap_control extension provides this functionality on Windows.

Comment: For all practical purposes, yes.

Answer (score 2):

In the Olden Days with CRT monitors it was possible to vsync in single buffered mode. There was a few milliseconds delay as the electron beam(s) returned from the bottom right of the screen back to the top left - the vsync interval - and if you could do all your rendering during that brief time, the screen updated smoothly without tearing.

Real hard-core programmers on consoles like the Atari 400/800 and the Amiga personal computer got more time to render by "racing the beam", updating the framebuffer RAM from top to bottom just ahead of the scanning electron beams.

You can still do something like this today. You can find details at Michael Abrash's blog at
http://blogs.valvesoftware.com/abrash, where he goes into detail about the latency problems with the Oculus Rift VR headset.

But it depends on knowing the exact timing details of the CPU, system bus, and display output; and also being able to write in assembler or low level C and control scheduling and interrupts. Using double buffering is way, way, easier.

Answer (score 1):

GDI and OpenGL have no VSYNC control.

In fact, OpenGL doesn't control the present of the rendered buffer and leave it to the system. On windows WGL controls VSYNC through extension [WGL_EXT_swap_control](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/wgl_swap_control.txt)